# How to update list view item after click?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp-xaml

I want to create a list view same list wifi of Window 10. When user click to a list item, it will show more information.

I don't know how to show that additional data in Listview Item of UWP app on click one item?

[before selected Wifi node](http://i387.photobucket.com/albums/oo318/evit15/Temp/before%20click.png)

[after selected Wifi node](http://i387.photobucket.com/albums/oo318/evit15/Temp/afterClick.png)

Comment: What do you mean by "update more information"? Do you mean that you don't know how to get more information about the selected network? Or that you don't know how to show that additional data in UWP app on click? Please, clarify that.

Comment: I don't know how to show that additional data in Listview Item of UWP app on click one item. I want same this picture (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/894076)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in order to show additional data you can use Grid or StackPanel or whatever suits your needs with visibility collapsed and when the user clicks the item it will be set to show. Here I demonstrated how you can do this with a simple ListView:

This is my MainPage:

```
<Page
    x:Class="App1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="using:App1"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Name="DummyPage"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Page.Resources>
        <local:BoolToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisibilityConverter" />
    </Page.Resources>

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <ListView
            Name="lvDummyData"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            IsItemClickEnabled="True"
            ItemClick="lvDummyData_ItemClick"
            SelectionMode="Single">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}" />

                        <StackPanel
                            Grid.Row="1"
                            Margin="0,20,0,0"
                            Visibility="{Binding ShowDetails, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Adress}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

This is my code behind:

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;

// The Blank Page item template is documented at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=402352&clcid=0x409

namespace App1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public ObservableCollection<DummyData> DummyData { get; set; }
        private DummyData tempSelectedItem;

        public MainPage()
        {
            DummyData = new ObservableCollection<DummyData>();

            DummyData.Add(new DummyData()
            {
                Adress = "London",
                FirstName = "Shella",
                LastName = "Schranz",
                ShowDetails = false
            });

            DummyData.Add(new DummyData()
            {
                Adress = "New York",
                FirstName = "Karyl",
                LastName = "Lotz",
                ShowDetails = false
            });

            DummyData.Add(new DummyData()
            {
                Adress = "Pasadena",
                FirstName = "Jefferson",
                LastName = "Kaur",
                ShowDetails = false
            });

            DummyData.Add(new DummyData()
            {
                Adress = "Berlin",
                FirstName = "Soledad",
                LastName = "Farina",
                ShowDetails = false
            });

            DummyData.Add(new DummyData()
            {
                Adress = "Brazil",
                FirstName = "Cortney",
                LastName = "Mair",
                ShowDetails = false
            });

            this.InitializeComponent();

            lvDummyData.ItemsSource = DummyData;
        }

        private void lvDummyData_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
        {
            DummyData selectedItem = e.ClickedItem as DummyData;

            selectedItem.ShowDetails = true;

            if (tempSelectedItem != null)
            {
                tempSelectedItem.ShowDetails = false;
                selectedItem.ShowDetails = true;
            }

            tempSelectedItem = selectedItem;
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void RaisePropertyChangeEvent(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public class DummyData : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Adress { get; set; }

        private bool showDetails;

        public bool ShowDetails
        {
            get
            {
                return showDetails;
            }
            set
            {
                showDetails = value;
                RaisePropertyChangeEvent(nameof(ShowDetails));
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void RaisePropertyChangeEvent(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

In my code-behind I have a variable tempSelectedItem which holds the previous clicked item so that you can hide its information.

In order to display and hide the information accordingly we need a simple BoolToVisibilityConverter:

```
using System;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;

namespace App1
{
    public class BoolToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            bool boolValue = (bool)value;
            return boolValue ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.